# Position card without changing heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a contact support page with Bootstrap 3. I have positioned a card on top of the header image, and set a padding on `140px` on the card:

```
.card-section { 
        position: relative; 
        bottom: 140px; 
    }
```

[See a demosite here](http://vouzalis.dk/Kontakt-Working.html).

The heading: "3 hurtige tips før du ringer til os" is now getting pushed `140px` down and I would like that heading is going just below  where the card is ending.

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve that?

The code is pretty long, so I only posted the relevant code. Please look the demosite for the whole page.

```css
.mk-page-header { 
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7), rgba(0,0,0,.7)), url(http://koed.dk/Static/Cms/333780ed-bd2b-4513-9186-af155e172a57.jpg)
        no-repeat; 
        position: relative; 
        background-size: cover; 
    }
    
    .page-caption { 
        padding-top: 170px; 
        padding-bottom: 174px; 
    }
    .page-title { 
        font-size: 46px; 
        line-height: 1; 
        color: #fff; 
        font-weight: 600; 
        text-align: center; 
    }
    
    .card-section { 
        position: relative; bottom: 140px; 
    }
    .card-block { 
        padding: 40px 80px 10px 80px;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px grey;
    }
    .section-title { 
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mk-page-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="page-caption">
                    <h1 class="page-title">KONTAKT VORES SUPPORT</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Card Section -->
<div class="card-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-block" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="contact-icon row">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h2>HAR DU SPØRGSMÅL?</h2>
                    <p>KOED har siden starten i 1993 beskæftiget sig udelukkende med BMW, og denne omfattende erfaring og viden vil vi gerne dele med dig. Vores store viden om BMW gør os i stand til at give dig svar på næsten enhver forespørgsel om mærket, hvad enten det handler om reservedele, tilbehør, hjælp til specialopgaver, guides til reparationer og meget mere.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="contact-icon row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img class="img-responsive-mk center-block" src="https://koed.dk/Static/Cms/6dfe32ba-7cff-443d-ab73-016dd2f6dca7.jpg"></img>
                            <h3 style="text-align:center;">Ring til os</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img class="img-responsive-mk center-block"  src="https://koed.dk/Static/Cms/57e5b8a2-871d-487f-90e4-ae8b8d170ca2.jpg"></img>
                            <h3 style="text-align:center;">Skriv til os</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img class="img-responsive-mk center-block"  src="https://koed.dk/Static/Cms/3caa853e-7da3-4e1f-9aa2-a04ee71901c9.jpg"></img>
                            <h3 style="text-align:center;">Facebook</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add also `margin-bottom: -140px;` to the .card-section where you already have `bottom: 140px;`.

But this is not the only solution.

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is a bad solution, but it is working. So I used this one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the whitespace is appearing is due to the `position` being set to `relative` on the `card-section`. Relative elements take up their space required in the normal document flow and then adjust their position.

To solve this, you should wrap the `card-section` in another div with a fixed height.

As for the flow of the document, the next row element is only concerned with the wrapper div and not the actual relatively positioned `card-section`.

```
.card-sec-wrap{
  height: 300px; // Adjust according to your need.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try this later on, when I have to optimize my code

Answer (score 0):

get rid of:

```
.card-section { 
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 140px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But how can I position the card section then :-)